# JPA @Query to handle null parameter value and like %?1%

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

`@Query("select t from Menu t where (?1 is null or t.name like %?1%)")`

in my case , this can handle null values, but when i have no null value `like %?1%` no effect , there is no way to do a fuzzy search .

I would like to have code=4 and find

```
4
546
345
```

but only find

```
4
```

Any help?

Comment: why `@Query("select t from Menu t where (t.name like %?1% or ?1 is null)")` can handle ???

Comment: There is no such thing as `@Query` in the JPA API. That is a SPRING annotation! This is JPQL you are talking about

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are trying to use got introduced with [ticket DATAJPA-292](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-292)
and in the comments you'll find the limitation that is causing problems to you:

> One thing to note is that references to the same parameter can only be equipped with the very same LIKE expression. The following query snippet is invalid:
>
> ```
> … firstname like %?1 and lastname like ?1%
> ```
>
> As we can only bind a single parameter once.

To get around that limitation you should be able to use SpEL expressions. Try the following:

```
@Query("select t from Menu t where (?1 is null or t.name like ?#{'%'+[0]+'%'})")
```

Not 100% sure, but I think this should work as well because it basically considers the to bind instances as separate parameters:

```
@Query("select t from Menu t where (?1 is null or t.name like %?#{[0]}%)")
```